# PHP headers code does not display address in email, instead show server default address

Tags: php, header

I tried many alternatives to this code but it does not show my display name.

```
$to = $email;
$subject = $subject;
$message = $msg;
$headers = 'From: info@test.com \r\n';
$headers .= "Reply-To: info@test.com \r\n";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding in the following convention.

```
$headers .= 'From: Mysitename <mysitename.com>' . "\r\n";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Thanks Ori a, I have tried it, still doesnt work, but when I block out the last two headers it works (but then my mail displays in plain text)
    $headers .= 'From: Mysitename <mysitename.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: max@a1websitepro.com'. "\r\n";
    //$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    //$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

Answer (score 0):

Ok I manage to make it work by re-arranging the headers, thanks for your input Ori.
       `$to = $email;`
        `$subject = $subject;`
       `$message = $msg;`
       `$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";`
       `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";`
       `$headers .= 'From: Info <info@testsite.com>' . "\r\n";`